# SherlockFragment and BaseAdapter: never call getView and getItem

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, baseadapter, getview

I already saw a bunch of questions but i didn't found an solution! What im doing wrong? Why getView is never called?!

Here`s my adapter:

```
 public class ConteudoAdapter<T extends IProgramacao> extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<T> list;
    private int resourceId;


    public ConteudoAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<T> list){
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.resourceId = resourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.v("test", "Returning count " + (this.list.size() != 0 ? this.list.size() : 0));
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

           View row = view;
           ViewHolder holder = null;
           T entidade = list.get(position);

            if(row == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);

                holder = new ViewHolder();          

                holder.tvTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                holder.tvTitle.setText(entidade.getTitulo());

                holder.tvConteudo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvConteudo);
                holder.tvConteudo.setText(entidade.getChamada());

                row.setTag(holder);
            }

        //  holder.ivImg = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.nivImg);
        //  holder.ivImg.setImageResource(entidade.);


        // IMAGE VIEW
        //      holder.ivImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //  il.get(list.get(position).getUrlImage(), il.getImageListener(holder.ivImg, R.drawable.load, R.drawable.error));

        //tvTitle.setText(entidade.getTitulo());

        return view;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        //public NetworkImageView nivImg;
        //public ImageView ivImg;
        public TextView tvTitle;
        public TextView tvConteudo;

    }
  }
```

Here`s how i call my adapter (inside an asynctask because im getting values from web (JSON):

```
public class CategoriaEventoFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    private View rootView;
    private EventoBO evento;
    private ListView lv;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            rootView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.categoria, container, false);

            CarregaDadosCategoriaEventoCaller carregaDadosCategoriaEventoCaller = new CarregaDadosCategoriaEventoCaller();
            carregaDadosCategoriaEventoCaller.execute((Void[]) null);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    public class CarregaDadosCategoriaEventoCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            evento = new EventoBO("http://urlhere");
            evento.popularListaImagemChamada("http://urlhere");

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewCategoria);

            lv.setAdapter(new ConteudoAdapter<Evento>(rootView.getContext(), R.layout.item, evento.getLista()));

        }
    }

    }


    }
```

XML FILES:

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/home_bg_branco"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvConteudo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

categoria.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewCategoria"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/home_bg_branco" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My LogCat Returns this for my verbose test:

```
09-02 17:13:27.322: V/test(24961): Returning count 5
09-02 17:13:27.322: V/test(24961): Returning count 5
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onCreateView()` you should be returning the rootView instead of the super.

Comment: Man, you solved my problem. If I could i upvote you! I was being so f. dumb